# How to scroll a PreferenceScreen?

Tags: testing, android-espresso

I'm trying to build a test that validates my `PreferenceScreen` view with Espresso. The text that I want to click on is at the bottom. So how do I scroll down in a `PreferenceScreen` with Espresso ?

I tried this code, but it did not work:

`onData(allOf(is(instanceOf(String.class)), is("Notifications"))).perform(click());`

Comment: I have not done it but I think you should use PreferenceMatchers : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/matcher/PreferenceMatchers.html

Answer (score 7):

This used to work:

```
onData(PreferenceMatchers.withTitleText("Notifications")).perform(click());
```

But nowadays you can use `RecyclerViewActions`:

```
onView(withId(androidx.preference.R.id.recycler_view))
    .perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItem(hasDescendant(withText("Notifications")), 
       click()));
```

Comment: Tried this solution; my view is completely visible, but it throws `No views in hierarchy found matching: is assignable from class: class android.widget.AdapterView`

Comment: Hi, I tried using PreferenceMatchers, but I wasn't able to run it. I always encountered android.support.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: is assignable from class: class android.widget.AdapterView.

Comment: @jzarsuelo: The PreferenceMatchers do not work with Android X and support library. Try using RecyclerViewActions. See this answer and my comment below it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52144554/2380518