# How to UI test Preference Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-espresso, ui-testing

I am setting up UI Tests and keep getting an `androidx.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching:`error message

My xml file looks like this with multiple categories

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:key="@string/key_preference_screen"
                  android:title="@string/sometitlename">
    <PreferenceCategory
        android:layout="@layout/category_layout"
        android:key="@string/key_pref_">
        <Preference
            android:key="@string/key"
            android:title="@string/pref_title"/>
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

I've tried variations of

````
onData(allOf(`is`(instanceOf(Preference::class.java)),
                 withKey(R.string.key),             
                 withTitle(R.string.pref_title)))
                .onChildView(withText(pref_title))
                .check(matches(isCompletelyDisplayed()))```
````

Answer (score 0):

Preference Matcher uses Recyclerview internally.Referenced from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52144554/4500099)

```
onView(withId(androidx.preference.R.id.recycler_view))
    .perform(
      RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(
        1,
        click()
      ))
```